# Email Without Intent

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email in my android application without using intent, as in i want it to be automatic. The email does not get sent to the recipient. I've looked at all the tutorials I could find, I still cant fix the problem. I added the three jar files.I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to my manifest, I changed the setting for my gmail to allow less secure logins. I dont get any errors in logcat and I've been following this method. [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.hoda.myapplication.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
import java.security.AccessController;
```

import java.security.Provider;

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {



    public JSSEProvider() {

        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");

        AccessController

                .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

                    public Void run() {

                        put("SSLContext.TLS",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");

                        put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");

                        put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");

                        put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",

                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");

                        return null;

                    }

                });

    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button does something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("email-sender@gmail.com", "password");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                            "This is Body",
                            "email-sender@gmail.com",
                            "email-receiver@yahoo.com");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: "I still cant fix the problem" What *is* the problem?

Comment: The email isn't sent to the recipient. Sorry should've mentioned it

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger to see if it works as intended? Did you try what happens if you are using a mail server other than gmail?

Comment: i tried with yahoo didnt work

Comment: everything runs as it should with debugger

Comment: I would guess then that the problem is something specific to the mail servers. Possibly something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801391/using-javamail-gmail-refusing-authentication-due-to-application-being-less-secu) but I'm just wildly guessing

Comment: my google account's security is lowered to allow the login and i dont get the same error as the linked post

Comment: Please make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android), then see the [debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) as well as the [Gmail instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what exactly the problem was with my solution but changing it to this fixed it for me! 
https://github.com/steveholt55/JavaMail-API-Android

For anyone's future reference, someone that looked at my code said the transport is getting disconnected but not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class AsyncTaskSendMail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String host="server142.web-hosting.com";//change accordingly
            final String user="*****@something.com";//change accordingly
            final String password="*****";//change accordingly

            String to="*****@something.com";//change accordingly

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
                        }
                    });

            try {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                message.setSubject("SAIM TEST MAIL");
                message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

                //send the message
                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("message sent successfully...");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            return "";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

        }

    }
```

Then execute whenever you want like this

```
new AsyncTaskSendMail().execute("Sending Email");//Passing Dummy Parameter
```

Comment: What is the deciding difference? That you're sending asynchronously? IIRC networking on the UI thread would have given an exception though

Comment: i get this "java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com" error